# Vim, 8 spaces after { <ENTER>

Tags: vim

I need to use four spaces as indent in project I'm working in. 
That is my .vimrc:

```
"Autouzupelnianie nawiasow
"inoremap { {<CR>}<C-O>O
inoremap { {}<LEFT>
inoremap [ []<LEFT>
inoremap ( ()<LEFT>

syntax on

set autoindent
set number "pokazywanie numerow lini
set modifiable
set write
filetype indent on "wlaczenie rozpoznawania wciec                                                                                                                
set showmatch "nawiasy                                                                                                                                           

"Backup                                                                                                                                                          
set backup                                                                                                                                                       
set backupdir=/home/mat/Backup/vim/                                                                                                                              

let g:html_use_css="1" "htmle uzywaja css                                                                                                                        

"Wrap                                                                                                                                                            
set linebreak                                                                                                                                                    
set wrap                                                                                                                                                         
set nolist                                                                                                                                                       

"Tabulacja                                                                                                                                                       
"                                                                                                                                                                
"set smartindent                                                                                                                                                 
set tabstop=4                                                                                                                                                    
set expandtab                                                                                                                                                    
set shiftwidth=4                                                                                                                                                 
set softtabstop=4                                                                                                                                                

"Plugin snippMate                                                                                                                                                
filetype plugin on
```

But when i hit { and then hit enter i've got:

```
{
        <8 spaces> SOMETHING
```

Comment: I had a quick look at the title and... what ? vim 8 ??

Comment: @François - Yeah, people don't seem to understand that you don't need to tag the title of the question when SO provides tags already...

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the filetype, a filetype plugin may be overriding your vimrc settings.  Check in `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim` and `$VIMRUNTIME/after/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim`.  Also `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/{filetype}.vim` and the `after` version of that.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem.

The solution is to command this after a colon `:`

```
set autoindent
set tabstop=4
```

Or you can command:

```
set tabstop=4 autoindent
```